# Node.js http.get request gets a totally different set of headers from a curl request

Tags: node.js, redirect, curl

Okay I'm trying to get the headers of this specific URL and node.js behaviour baffles me.

My code :

```
var http = require('http');

var req = http.get("http://listen.radionomy.com/abc-lounge", function(res) {
   console.log("headers: ", res.headers); 
});
```

Prints out :

> headers:  { 'cache-control': 'private',   'content-type': 'text/html;
>   charset=utf-8',   server: 'Microsoft-IIS/7.5',   'x-aspnet-version':
>   '4.0.30319',   'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET',   date: 'Tue, 28 Jan 2014
>   14:18:27 GMT',   'content-length': '8309' }

Now I tried out the command line curl with headers :

> curl -I http://listen.radionomy.com/abc-lounge

This prints out exactly what I'm looking for (The redirect url) :

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found
>  Cache-Control: private
>  Content-Length:
>   0
>  Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>  Location:
>   http://streaming.radionomy.com/ABC-Lounge
>  Server:
>   Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>  X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.0
>  X-AspNet-Version:
>   4.0.30319
>  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>  Date: Tue, 28 Jan 2014 14:19:20 GMT

I don't understand why node is getting a different set of headers. It should not follow redirects by default. I don't even think this is a redirect issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I fake a `curl` request by adding some `headers` to your `http.get` like this:**

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    host: 'listen.radionomy.com',
    path: '/abc-lounge',
    headers: {
        'user-agent': 'curl/7.31.0',
        'accept': '*/*'         
    }
};

var req = http.get(options, function(res) {
   console.log('status:', res.statusCode)
   console.log("headers: ", res.headers); 
});
```

**Output will be:**

```
status: 302
headers:  { 'cache-control': 'private',
  'content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
  location: 'http://streaming.radionomy.com/ABC-Lounge',
  server: 'Microsoft-IIS/7.5',
  'x-aspnetmvc-version': '5.0',
  'x-aspnet-version': '4.0.30319',
  'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET',
  date: 'Tue, 28 Jan 2014 15:02:16 GMT',
  'content-length': '0' }
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Strangely listen.radionomy.com answers you with a different set of headers if you don't pass in the "user-agent". Nothing wrong with node here, like I thought this was not a redirect issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `http.get` actually follows the redirect

Comment: Node's `http.get()` shouldn't follow. Trying a "share" link from SO and it includes `location: '/questions/...'` in the log.